# Formating a tikz-cd quiver with big entries to have parallel arrows

Tags: tikz-cd

I want to draw a nice looking Auslander-Reiten quivers using tikzcd but my entries are getting quite big which kills the formating a little. Is there (an easy) way to make AR-quivers look good? I would like to achive that the "quares" are all the same size. Or for an equivalent effect, that the arrows in the "rows" and "columns" are parallel.

I was able to work with smallmatrix quite well until this point, but for quivers where the entires are very big in one direction and small in the other the formating is not quite perfect.

My version looks like this:

[image: My version looks like this]

As you can see it is quite parallel but not perfect.

[I am using the quiver website and have linked it here.](https://q.uiver.app/#q=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)

The code is displayed below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools,thmtools}

\usepackage{quiver}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep = small]
    \&\& {\begin{smallmatrix}  && 3 & 4 & 5& \end{smallmatrix}} \\
    \& {\ \begin{smallmatrix} 1& 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \end{smallmatrix}} \&\& { \begin{smallmatrix}  & & 3  & 4  &  5  &  6  \end{smallmatrix}} \\
    {\begin{smallmatrix} &2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \end{smallmatrix}} \&\& { \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2&3  &  4& 5 & 6\end{smallmatrix}} \&\& {\begin{smallmatrix} &  & 3 & 4 & & \end{smallmatrix}} \\
    \& { \begin{smallmatrix} &2&3  &  4& 5 & 6\end{smallmatrix}} \&\& {\begin{smallmatrix} 1& 2 & 3 & 4 &  \end{smallmatrix}} \&\& {\begin{smallmatrix}  &&3&&&  \end{smallmatrix}} \\
    \&\& {\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 3  & 4 &  & \end{smallmatrix}} \&\& { \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2  & 3 &  & &\end{smallmatrix}} \\
    \&\&\& {\begin{smallmatrix} & 2&  3& &  & &\end{smallmatrix}}
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=4-4, to=5-5]
    \arrow[from=6-4, to=5-5]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=6-4]
    \arrow[dotted, from=5-5, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=4-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=4-2, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=4-2]
    \arrow[dotted, from=3-3, to=3-1]
    \arrow[from=5-5, to=4-6]
    \arrow[dotted, from=4-6, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=4-4, to=3-5]
    \arrow[from=3-5, to=4-6]
    \arrow[dotted, from=3-5, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=2-4]
    \arrow[from=2-4, to=3-5]
    \arrow[dotted, from=2-4, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=1-3, to=2-4]
    \arrow[dotted, from=4-4, to=4-2]
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `column sep = small`  use `column sep = {11mm,between origins}` (or `sep = {11mm,between origins}` if you want the rows also). Be sure to add the correct number of columns to the first row:

```
\&\& {\begin{smallmatrix}  && 3 & 4 & 5& \end{smallmatrix}} \&\&\&\\
```

[image]

Also, it's simpler code if you don't use `smallmatrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={11mm,between origins}, font=\scriptsize]
   && 3\ 4\ 5 &&&\\
   & 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5 && 3\ 4\ 5\ 6 \\
   2\ 3\ 4\ 5 && 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6 && 3\ 4 \\
   & 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6 && 1\ 2\ 3\ 4 && 3 \\
   && 2\ 3\ 4 && 1\ 2\ 3\\
   &&& 2\ 3
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=4-4, to=5-5]
    \arrow[from=6-4, to=5-5]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=6-4]
    \arrow[dotted, from=5-5, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=4-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=4-2, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=4-2]
    \arrow[dotted, from=3-3, to=3-1]
    \arrow[from=5-5, to=4-6]
    \arrow[dotted, from=4-6, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=4-4, to=3-5]
    \arrow[from=3-5, to=4-6]
    \arrow[dotted, from=3-5, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=2-4]
    \arrow[from=2-4, to=3-5]
    \arrow[dotted, from=2-4, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=1-3, to=2-4]
    \arrow[dotted, from=4-4, to=4-2]
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty hack: use a `\makebox` to make sure that all your entries have the same width (I added a few more digits to make the misalignment more obvious)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools,thmtools}

\usepackage{quiver}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep = small,row sep=1.2cm]
    \&\& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix}  && 3 & 4 & 5& \end{smallmatrix}$}} \\
    \& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix} 1& 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \end{smallmatrix}$}} \&
    \& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix}  & & 3  & 4  &  5  &  6 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9  \end{smallmatrix}$}} \\
    {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix} &2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \end{smallmatrix}$}} \&
    \& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2&3  &  4& 5 & 6\end{smallmatrix}$}} \&
    \& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix} &  & 3 & 4 & & \end{smallmatrix}$}} \\
    \& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix} &2&3  &  4& 5 & 6\end{smallmatrix}$}} \&
    \& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix} 1& 2 & 3 & 4 &  \end{smallmatrix}$}} \&
    \& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix}  &&3&&&  \end{smallmatrix}$}} \\
    \&
    \& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 3  & 4 &  & \end{smallmatrix}$}} \&
    \& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2  & 3 &  & &\end{smallmatrix}$}} \\
    \&\&
    \& {\makebox[1.1cm]{$\begin{smallmatrix} & 2&  3& &  & &\end{smallmatrix}$}}
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=4-4, to=5-5]
    \arrow[from=6-4, to=5-5]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=6-4]
    \arrow[dotted, from=5-5, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=4-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=4-2, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=4-2]
    \arrow[dotted, from=3-3, to=3-1]
    \arrow[from=5-5, to=4-6]
    \arrow[dotted, from=4-6, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=4-4, to=3-5]
    \arrow[from=3-5, to=4-6]
    \arrow[dotted, from=3-5, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=2-4]
    \arrow[from=2-4, to=3-5]
    \arrow[dotted, from=2-4, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=1-3, to=2-4]
    \arrow[dotted, from=4-4, to=4-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep = small,row sep=1.2cm]
    \&\& {\begin{smallmatrix}  && 3 & 4 & 5& \end{smallmatrix}} \\
    \& {\ \begin{smallmatrix} 1& 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \end{smallmatrix}} \&\& { \begin{smallmatrix}  & & 3  & 4  &  5  &  6 & 9  & 9  & 9  & 9   \end{smallmatrix}} \\
    {\begin{smallmatrix} &2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \end{smallmatrix}} \&\& { \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2&3  &  4& 5 & 6\end{smallmatrix}} \&\& {\begin{smallmatrix} &  & 3 & 4 & & \end{smallmatrix}} \\
    \& { \begin{smallmatrix} &2&3  &  4& 5 & 6\end{smallmatrix}} \&\& {\begin{smallmatrix} 1& 2 & 3 & 4 &  \end{smallmatrix}} \&\& {\begin{smallmatrix}  &&3&&&  \end{smallmatrix}} \\
    \&\& {\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 3  & 4 &  & \end{smallmatrix}} \&\& { \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2  & 3 &  & &\end{smallmatrix}} \\
    \&\&\& {\begin{smallmatrix} & 2&  3& &  & &\end{smallmatrix}}
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=4-4, to=5-5]
    \arrow[from=6-4, to=5-5]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=5-3, to=6-4]
    \arrow[dotted, from=5-5, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=4-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=4-2, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=4-2]
    \arrow[dotted, from=3-3, to=3-1]
    \arrow[from=5-5, to=4-6]
    \arrow[dotted, from=4-6, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=4-4, to=3-5]
    \arrow[from=3-5, to=4-6]
    \arrow[dotted, from=3-5, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=2-4]
    \arrow[from=2-4, to=3-5]
    \arrow[dotted, from=2-4, to=2-2]
    \arrow[from=2-2, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=1-3, to=2-4]
    \arrow[dotted, from=4-4, to=4-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(result of new code on the left, old code on the right)

Comment: Sorry for the edit. Got cofused as i did not have edditing rights before. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Bobior You're welcome! And you should accept @ Sandy G's answer, it is much better!

Comment: Yes. I did. It makes editing it much more doable.

Comment: @Bobior Great, thanks!